# CSS/SVG stroke animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, path

I have this circle, will be animated when clicking on the h1.

Everything works ok except that I want that the animatation to start from the bottom to right like:

[image]

Not from right middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zj7w81ss/

```
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="80px" height="80px" viewBox="0 0 16 16" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6.215"></circle>
</svg>
```

How should I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rotate your circle using the transform attribute:

`transform="rotate(degrees centerX centerY)"`

```
<circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6.215" transform="rotate(90 8 8)"></circle>
```

To change the direction of the line animation you can change you initial `stroke-dashoffset` in the CSS to `stroke-dashoffset: -39;`

Edit: [tested on your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zj7w81ss/1/)